# Linux, install large update > updates break running programs > install more programs OR reboot then install more programs?

Tags: linux, installation, updates

Ok so updates can break programs. I just installed Fedora 37 Cinnamon and had Cinnamon continually crash after the update. Technically I know I can get around this by closing and relaunching any affected program, but charting out dependencies to restart on a large update sounds like a nightmare, and is a lot slower than reboot, so that’s what I usually choose for my desktop.

I was setting up an Ansible script and am wondering if I needed to reboot before I installed my choice of packages, or if installing with broken programs running might screw things up some?

A more technically accurate question would be:

**Do package managers and the install scripts that get run reliably only check the files, or do they sometimes talk to the running programs that might be "update broken"?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Do **not** close your eyes and continue installing new software.
2. In this situation, your software is probably broken due to not upgraded dependencies. First try a `dnf reinstall <package-name>` of the software in question.
3. In general: Check the dependencies: `dnf repoquery --unsatisfied`
4. If you installed Cinnamon (or other software) manually (not from repo) you also have to upgrade it manually and verify their dependencies.

As direct answer to your question:
First fix your dependencies, then reboot and test. Installing all at once should be ok.

Preferably use the shell, not a GUI tool as GUI applications have more dependencies and rely more on other software. — Try to minimize the sources for possible errors in an unstable system while fixing it.